# Can I enforce only one tick to be selected when adding a new list item

Tags: list, custom-list, splistitem

Hi (Sharepoint Virgin here.... [But been programming .NET for years now])

Iv'e just recently had to start doing some Sharepoint based work, and as a result have had to basically throw myself in on a crash course, learning to use it.

In one of the tasks I have, I'm required to create a custom list called a JobQueue.

This list looks as follows:

[image: Sharepoint Custom List Definition]

As you can see, there are three boolean items, IsTodo, IsInProgress and IsDone.

A job can only be in one of the 3 states at any given time, so is it possible for me when a user of the site adds a new item to the to enforce only one item being ticked at a time.

Ideally, I'd like that if IsInProgress is ticked, then the other two are automatically un-ticked, or if IsDone is ticked, then IsTodo and IsInProgress become un-ticked, I'd also like to be able to make this happen both when adding a new item, and when editing an existing one.

Is there a way I can make this happen just using the standard Sharepoint stuff, or am I going to have to start writing extensions for this?

Many thanks
Shawty

Comment: You could use a single choice field with three values:  To Do, In Progress and Done.  That should serve what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the three state fields to a Choice column with 3 choices "To Do", "In Progress", "Done". At the bottom of the Column definition there will be a default option. Set this to the To Do. You can set to type radio button.

[image]

This will look like this in form

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, that did the trick.  Now I just need to figure out how to change it's display representation. :-)  The title will display in one of 3 columns horizontally, depending on that status, I foresee more sharepoint questions in my future :-)